# Function arguments are negative offsets with respect to rbp (as far as i understand, they should be at positive offset)

Tags: c, assembly, x86, x86-64

Consider the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int func(int arg1)
{
    int arg2;
    arg2 = 0;
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    func(2);
    return 0;
}
```

Running gcc with -g and starting gdb and then viewing the addresses of rbp, arg1 and arg2 gives me this:

```
Breakpoint 1, func (arg1=2) at test.c:8
8           return 1;
(gdb) p &arg1
$1 = (int *) 0x7ffffffedc6c
(gdb) p &arg2
$2 = (int *) 0x7ffffffedc7c
(gdb) i r rbp
rbp            0x7ffffffedc80   0x7ffffffedc80
```

Expectation: The address of arg1 shoud've been more than rbp and address of arg2 should've been less than rbp. (I used this for understanding about stack frames: [Link](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Disassembly/Functions_and_Stack_Frames)

What's happening: Both the addresses are less than rbp.

What have I understood wrong?

Run on Ubuntu WSL.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/7zKE5q - Some parameters are passed through the register and not the stack. (in this case `arg1` in `edi` and the return value in `eax`) while the compiler allocates some space on the stuck of the local frame so that those variables could have valid address.

Comment: ohh got it, thanks. Do you know what data is present between (rbp-4) and (rbp-20) (from the assembly code shown in that link)?

Comment: I am not sure I have a solid answer for that...

Comment: Hmm... I'll look around on google for that,  Thanks a lot :)

Comment: You are welcome! Good luck!

Comment: The reason you see data below RBP (without adjusting RSP) is because the compiler is assuming by default that the Red Zone (128 bytes immediately below RSP) are available and wont be clobbered. You'd get slightly different code if you told it there is no red zone with option `-mno-red-zone`  . Looking at unoptimized code and stack usage isn't very valuable as the code generator will not be trying to make stack usage more efficient. Often though the gaps in the stack are for things like alignment.